# Reading MaxLength from MetadataWorkspace

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I found a way here to read from **MetadataWorkspace**. Tried to read just specific field MaxLength. It worked well.
But, Can't change it to work as a method that I can call, and the problem is that:

```
var tables = workspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.SSpace);
```

return the complete entities, and I have to know the index number to the required one, I can't use the name!.

```
var ET = tables[4].Properties[propertyName].MaxLength;
```

How can I re-write this to be like:

```
var ET = tables[entityName].Properties[propertyName].MaxLength;
```

This is my complete method:

```
public int GetMaxLenth(string entityName, string propertyName)
{
    var context = new CmsDbContext();
    ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
     MetadataWorkspace workspace = objContext.MetadataWorkspace;

     var tables = workspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.SSpace);
     var ET = tables[4].Properties[propertyName].MaxLength;
     return ET.Value;
}
```

How to do it, please.

**[Edit]**

Thnaks to Ivan Stoev for his help. I moved to EF Core, and the code become shorter. I wish to help someone else, This is it:

```
public static int GetMaxLenth(DbContext context, string entityName, string propertyName)
{
    var tables = context.Model.GetEntityTypes();
    var table = tables.First(type => type.ClrType.Name == entityName);
    return table.FindProperty(propertyName).GetMaxLength() ?? -1;
}
```

It has three para:

1. The name of DbContext.
2. The Table Name.
3. The Field Name

Regards to all.

Comment: Which version of EF ?

Comment: Off the top of my head, In 6.1 you could try something like dbContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.CSpace).Where(x => x.Name == "MyTableName").Properties["MyPropertyName"].MaxLength.Value;

Comment: Thanks. I did as you suggest, but got problem with .Properties can't be resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no exact predefined method for that. The closest is [MetadataWorkspace.GetType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.metadataworkspace.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx), but it requires namespace name in addition to entity name. So you have to resort to some traditional method, like LINQ `First` for instance:

```
// ...
var table = tables.First(type => type.Name == entityName);
var ET = table.Properties[propertyName].MaxLength;
// ...
```

Comment: I am moving to EF Core, This approach is not working. How to solve it, please.

Comment: In EF Core it should be something like this: `var tables = context.Model.GetEntityTypes(); var table = tables.First(type => type.Name == entityName); return table.FindProperty(propertyName).GetMaxLength() ?? -1;`