# Order Creation of DbSet in DbContext in EF 6.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I need to order the creation of DbSet<> in DbContext. Because of:

- I notice that I have problem (violation in foreign key) with **Seed** method.
- Referring to this [Reading MaxLength from MetadataWorkspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436245/reading-maxlength-from-metadataworkspace) that I couldn't solve. I need to be sure about the number of each exact entity.

Btw, the DbSets are already order in the DbContext, but it seems that no effect when creating the migration.

In my DbContext:

```
public class CmsDbContext : DbContext
{
    // Basic
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<District> Districts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Province> Provinces { get; set; }
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Area> Areas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomerType> CustomerTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IdType> IdTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IncomeType> IncomeTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OutcomeType> OutcomeTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PaymentType> PaymentTypes { get; set; }
}
```

As you see, the Country is the first.
After issuing

```
add-migration initial
```

The order of DbSets are not as I want:

```
public partial class initial : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Area",
            c => new
                {
                    AreaId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    CityId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    AreaArabicName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 35, unicode: false),
                    AreaEnglishName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 35, unicode: false),
                    AddedDate = c.DateTime(),
                    ModifiedDate = c.DateTime(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.AreaId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.City", t => t.CityId)
            .Index(t => t.CityId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.City",
            c => new
                {
                    CityId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    ProvinceId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    CityArabicName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 35, unicode: false),
                    CityEnglishName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 35, unicode: false),
                    AddedDate = c.DateTime(),
                    ModifiedDate = c.DateTime(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.CityId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Province", t => t.ProvinceId)
            .Index(t => t.ProvinceId);
```

and so on...

Notice that **Country** is not the first table to be created.

When I issued:

```
update-database
```

The database is created, the table also created, but seed method didn't. I got exception:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Area_dbo.City_CityId".
```

This wouldn't happend if I stop seeding to **City**.

I wish the problem is clear now.

This is the **seed** of **City**

```
class CityDefaultData
{
    private readonly string[,] _cities = new string[,]
    {
        {"1", "الرياض", "Riyadh"},
        {"2", "جدة", "Jeddah"},
        {"3", "الدمام", "Dammam"},
        {"4", "بريدة", "Buraidah"}
    };

    private readonly List<City> _newCitiess = new List<City>();

    public List<City> GetDefaultCity()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i <= _cities.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            _newCitiess.Add(new City()
            {
                ProvinceId = Convert.ToInt32(_cities[i, 0]),
                CityArabicName = _cities[i, 1],
                CityEnglishName = _cities[i, 2]
            });
        }
        return _newCitiess;
    }
}
```

The **seed** of **Area**:

```
class AreaDefaultData
{
    private readonly string[,] _areas = new string[,]
    {
        {"1", "السلام", "Salam"},
        {"1", "العليا", "Olayya"},
        {"1", "الروابي", "Rawabi"},
        {"1", "القدس", "Quds"},
        {"1", "المنار", "Manar"},
        {"2", "السلام", "Salam"},
        {"2", "العليا", "Olayya"},
        {"2", "الروابي", "Rawabi"},
        {"2", "القدس", "Quds"},
        {"2", "المنار", "Manar"}
    };


    private readonly List<Area> _newAreas = new List<Area>();

    public List<Area> GetDefaultArea()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i <= _areas.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            _newAreas.Add(new Area()
            {
                CityId = Convert.ToInt32(_areas[i, 0]),
                AreaArabicName = _areas[i, 1],
                AreaEnglishName = _areas[i, 2]
            });
        }
        return _newAreas;
    }
}
```

This is my DbInitialize

```
class DbInitializer
{
    public void DataSeed(CmsDbContext context)
    {
        // Country
        List<Country> coutry =
            new CountryDefaultData().GetDefaultCountry();
        coutry.ForEach(e => context.Countries.Add(e));
        context.Countries.AddOrUpdate();

        // District
        List<District> district =
            new DistrictDefaultData().GetDefaultDistrict();
        district.ForEach(e => context.Districts.Add(e));
        context.Districts.AddOrUpdate();

        // Province
        List<Province> province =
            new ProvinceDefaultData().GetDefaultProvince();
        province.ForEach(e => context.Provinces.Add(e));
        context.Provinces.AddOrUpdate();

        // City
        List<City> city =
            new CityDefaultData().GetDefaultCity();
        city.ForEach(e => context.Cities.Add(e));
        context.Cities.AddOrUpdate();

        // Area
        List<Area> area =
            new AreaDefaultData().GetDefaultArea();
        area.ForEach(e => context.Areas.Add(e));
        context.Areas.AddOrUpdate();

        // Id Type
        List<IdType> idType =
            new IdTypeDefultData().GetDefaultIdTypes();
        idType.ForEach(e => context.IdTypes.Add(e));
        context.IdTypes.AddOrUpdate();

        // Customer Type
        List<CustomerType> customerType =
            new CustomerTypeDefaultData().GetDefaultCustomerType();
        customerType.ForEach(e => context.CustomerTypes.Add(e));
        context.CustomerTypes.AddOrUpdate();

        // Income Type
        List<IncomeType> incomeType =
            new IncomeTypeDefaultData().GetDefaultIncomeType();
        incomeType.ForEach(e => context.IncomeTypes.Add(e));
        context.IncomeTypes.AddOrUpdate();

        // Outcome Type
        List<OutcomeType> outcomeType =
            new OutcomeTypeDefaultData().GetDefaultOutcomeType();
        outcomeType.ForEach(e => context.OutcomeTypes.Add(e));
        context.OutcomeTypes.AddOrUpdate();

        // Payment Type
        List<PaymentType> paymentType =
            new PaymentTypeDefaultData().GetDefaultPaymentType();
        paymentType.ForEach(e => context.PaymentTypes.Add(e));
        context.PaymentTypes.AddOrUpdate();
    }
}
```

And, finally:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<CMS.Model.Domain.CmsDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(CMS.Model.Domain.CmsDbContext context)
    {
        DbInitializer all = new DbInitializer();
        all.DataSeed(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Please show code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Gert Arnold, thanks for your care. I updated the question.

Comment: The Seed method causes the problem and that's what you should show. The  rest is irrelevant. If the database is created alright (which it is), why worry about the order of `CreateTable` statements?

Comment: Because, I want to know that table number 1 is Country, so this will solve my problem in my other post. Also, I believe this is the problem with Seed. Now during the development, when I need to issue update-database, I stop seeding to city, and after update-database, I enable it again and update-database again, and all work well.

Comment: It's still unclear. Where is the seed code you are talking about?

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, I added the seed of city and other classes. I hope this will now clear. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to think that after a database table is created, it is seeded immediately. But how would EF even know how do that?  The database is created first, the *entire* database. *Then* the seed method is executed. The problem is that your seeded data don't have proper references to one another, in particular: `Area`s without `City` references.

Comment: I'm with @GertArnold. As a side note, your `AddOrUpdate` calls do nothing.

Comment: **AddOrUpdate** do inserting to the database. The problem as I mention is from seeding; as it seeds **City** before **Country**. As I said, if I stop seeding to **City**, all seeds will be done well from the first time.

Comment: Listen, your empty `AddOrUpdate` calls really don't do anything. If you think that, please look at the documentation. The data are inserted by the `Add(e)` statements. You should remove the `Add` statements and properly deploy the `AddOrUpdate` statements. And the order of the statements doesn't matter. EF determines the insert order itself when `SaveChanges` is called (which I don't see by the way). If you need more help, I'd suggest you also show the seeded `Area` data.

Comment: I added the **seed** of **Area**. Really, I got confused here. If **EF** determine the insert order, how come doesn't work if I seed them all, while it is working if I stop seeding to **City** at first time try, and work in the second, after the first seed in complete!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally after clearing away some misconceptions about the order of creating tables, seeding data, and the order of adding data, we've arrived at a point that some hopefully helpful insights can be given.

#### AddOrUpdate

This method is specifically meant for seeding data, so you were on the right track. But you didn't use it effectively because you didn't enter any entities. Here's an example of how you could use it:

```
var cities = new City[]
{
    new City { ProvinceId = 1, CityArabicName = "الرياض", CityEnglishName = "Riyadh"},
    new City  { ProvinceId = 2, CityArabicName = "جدة",  CityEnglishName = "Jeddah"},
    new City  { ProvinceId = 3, CityArabicName = "الدمام", CityEnglishName = "Dammam"},
    new City  { ProvinceId = 4, CityArabicName = "بريدة", CityEnglishName = "Buraidah"}
};
context.Cities.AddOrUpdate(c => c.CityArabicName, cities);
```

The lambda expression `c => c.CityArabicName` tells EF to look for cities by `CityArabicName`. If a city with that name already exists, the city is marked as modified, otherwise it is marked as new. Note that `AddOrUpdate` doesn't save any data, that's done by one `SaveChanges` call at the end.

If you don't supply this lambda expression, EF assumes that the primary key, `CityId`, is the key by which to look for existing cities. Well, they're not specified (i.e. `0`) in `cities`. Therefore no existing cities are found and the `Seed` method will always duplicate your cities. So when primary keys are auto generated you always need some *natural key* by which EF will recognize existing entities.

But even if you'd enter primary key values in your seed data, EF would ignore them. **With auto-generated primary keys, you can't seed primary key values.**

#### How is this related to your problem?

Well, if primary key values are unpredictable, **neither can you seed hard-coded foreign keys values.** That's exactly what you do with `Area`s. Now, admittedly, it's weird that you get the FK violation when cities *are* seeded, and not when they aren't. After all, there's a big chance that `CityId`s 1 and 2 will be generated (although Sql Server can decide to start generating at much higher values). So I can't really explain your findings, but I *do* know you have to fix your seeding code anyway.

#### Fixing it

There are two ways to tie objects together in seeding scripts:

1. Wrap the whole script in a `TransactionScope`, call `SaveChanges` multiple time, and capture the generated primary key values to assign them to entity properties in subsequent steps. I don't really like this option, but sometimes you have to use it. A better option is -
2. Create object graphs. That is, create entities with nested entities and save them by one `SaveChanges` call. In your case that would mean that `City` should have a navigation property ...

   ```
   public virtual ICollection<Area> Areas { get; set; }
   ```

   ... and that you should populate the areas in the seeded entities:

   ```
   var cities = new City[]
   {
       new City { ProvinceId = 1, CityArabicName = "الرياض", CityEnglishName = "Riyadh",
                  Areas = areas1 },
       new City { ProvinceId = 2, CityArabicName = "جدة",  CityEnglishName = "Jeddah",
                  Areas = areas2 },
       new City { ProvinceId = 3, CityArabicName = "الدمام", CityEnglishName = "Dammam"},
       new City { ProvinceId = 4, CityArabicName = "بريدة", CityEnglishName = "Buraidah"}
   };
   ```

   ... where `areas1` and `areas2` obviously are the two collections of areas belonging to the first two cities. Now you're going to `AddOrUpdate` the cities only, because if a city must be added, its areas must be added too.

#### Next steps

This doesn't tell the whole story. Seeding related data can be hard. What if you have to add an `Area` to a `City` in a later release of the application? What if you should update an `Area`, or delete one? This will often require more verbose steps that don't use `AddOrUpdate` anymore.

Comment: Instead of **AddOrUpdate()**, I called **SaveChanges()**. So, context.Cities.AddOrUpdate() will be context.SaveChanges(). It works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For seeding
Create object of `Country`, in it add `District`, in `District` add `Province`, in `Province` add `City` > `Area` > `TypeID` in `TypeID` add customer's data of that hierarchy.
Now add another `Area` or `TypeID` to the `City` or `Area` respectively.

So that your object of `Country` have multiple districts, each district have multiple provinces and each province have multiple city ... like-wise.

Now add this object `Country` to the function:

`context.Countries.Add(`

And in this add multiple countries to the context.

Comment: I will tried it. It sees to be **nested** too much. Thanks